# Why is having dust on your skin not considered carrying on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

If the prohibition on carrying on Shabbos can apply even to extra saliva in one's mouth,* why doesn't it apply to the many extremely small things that are inevitably on one's person, such as dust?

*Please note that I am asking about dust, etc., on your skin, not your clothes. I found an answer for when it's on your clothes, particularly if it's attached.*

*Source: "The 39 Melachot," by Rabbi Dovid Ribiat, Vol. 4, section three, chapter V, 29c:

> Walking with an accumulation of saliva: One who feels an accumulation
>   of saliva in his mouth that has collected and is ready to be expelled
>   should not continue walking in R'shus Harabim, but should stop and
>   expel the excess fluid (on the street, not in a trash can - see a
>   above). He should certainly not walk home or to any R'shus Hayochid
>   with the excess saliva. The reason here is because some Poskim regard
>   the excess saliva in this state as a separate entity and no longer
>   part of the body. In this context, it is considered a Masui, and
>   walking with it through R'shus Harabim, or to a R'shus Hayochid is
>   Hotzoa.

There are several footnotes to the text. I couldn't really read them, but gathered that sources are the Mishnah Berurah, S' shin nun, s"k yud beis and yud daled, and the Mishnah Berurah שם, not sure.

Comment: Please find an exact source, if you can. It's been a while, but I'm *pretty* sure that small things you don't want and carry unintentionally are not forbidden. (And I'm bewildered by the phlegm.)

Comment: I had no idea of what you said in your first sentence. If you can link that or cite from it, that would be nice. But, since it mentions that, it would make me wonder how anyone could ever go to or return from shul on Shabbat when it's raining or snowing. For that matter, on a nice day in the Spring, you can get pollen all over your clothes.

Comment: @kouty Your 2nd comment seems to contradict the first. Who wants drool in his mouth? And who wants mucus in his nose? (Well you do need SOME, actually, for health reasons.)

Comment: @kouty That might be a matter of an individual deliberately "pooling" drool in their mouth that they would otherwise swallow. The fact that you're doing so is an intrinsic statement of worth.

Comment: @Shokhet "(And I'm bewildered by the phlegm)" - In hindsight, now that I read this ruling, it would explain much about what I saw some of the old men in the shul I grew up in doing about 40 years ago. I guess it's not so bewildering?

Comment: I just don't see how phlegm could be something that is forbidden to carry, @DanF. That's the reason I asked for a precise citation; I suspect that SAH may misremember something (but I'll believe it if I can look it up and verify it).

Comment: Also, DanF, about your response to @kouty; I don't think they meant that there is a rabbinic prohibition on Shabbos. I think they meant in general (but again, I could be wrong). kouty, would you care to clarify?

Comment: @Shokhet Found it, please see edited post

Comment: @DanF et al You too

Comment: Thank you for the added information, and the ping, @SAH.

Comment: @SAH Thanks. It confirms what I suspected - **excess** saliva. I.e., it is an "unnecessary" item. I'm not sure why anyone wants this in their mouth, but, I would imagine that if someone clears his throat, he needs to spit.

Comment: @DanF You're welcome. But dust i.e. on skin is also "unnecessary," so why wouldn't it be a problem?

Comment: It looks like the carrying rules--perhaps coincidentally, perhaps not--correspond substantially to what is considered chatzitzah for mikvah (obviously with many exceptions such as clothes). You have to blow your nose before mikvah, for example, according to what I've learned. For mikvah you would be responsible for removing dust, I think; does this apply to carrying, too?

Comment: @DanF The old men in your shul were spitting during Aleinu only because they didn't want to be mechalel shabbos

Answer (score 6):

Mishna Shabbat 7, 3:

> THEY ALSO STATED ANOTHER GENERAL PRINCIPLE: WHATEVER IS FIT TO PUT AWAY AND SUCH IS [GENERALLY] PUT AWAY, AND ONE CARRIES IT OUT ON THE SABBATH, HE IS LIABLE TO A SIN-OFFERING ON ITS ACCOUNT.
>
> BUT WHATEVER IS NOT FIT TO PUT AWAY AND SUCH IS NOT [GENERALLY] PUT AWAY, AND ONE CARRIES IT OUT ON THE SABBATH, ONLY HE THAT PUT IT AWAY IS LIABLE.

Mishna Shabbat 9, 6, about specific dusts:

> [PIECES] OF THE ALTAR STONES OR THE ALTAR EARTH, MOTH-EATEN SCROLLS OR THEIR MOTH-EATEN MANTLES, OF WHATEVER QUANTITY, [HE IS CULPABLE].

Mishna Eruvin 10, 5:

> R`JUDAH RULED: EVEN WHERE A PERSON'S SPITTLE ACCUMULATED IN HIS MOUTH, HE MUST NOT WALK FOUR CUBITS BEFORE HE SPAT OUT.

*See SA OC 350, 3 and BetYosef there.*

Drool that he want to spite in the mouth is a pb of hotsaa according to rabbi Yehuda. Poskim discusse if this is the halacha. The prohibition is perhaps deorayta (see Beur Halacha siman 350)

For dust see SA hilchot  Shabbat 301, 46

to walk with a dress soaked is prohibited rabbinically because of th risk to spin it. But hotsaa is not a problem, despite that the water is not a part of the dress.

## Conclusion:

The question about nasal mucus which was moved and come down from is initial place is a problem, may be even deorayita (Beur Halacha 350), according to the mishna in Eruvin. As if it is somewhat you want to launch. To launch is prohibited deorayta because the action of launching give importance to the launched object. Carrying an object from one place to another is mel'echet hotsaa if this object has an effective/potential value, function. This is not the case for dust.

Comment: so with nasal mucus should you "launch" or not (if you find it on your person in a r'shus harabim)? Just want to know if there might be a different answer from my sefer's, which says "spit on the street," which is problematic, at least for me. I hope never to be in this situation, seriously

Comment: You bring great sources. Thanks. And much of your answer was supplied before I edited my question, so I hesitate to nitpick based on the revised question. Still, I am seeking an answer about the deal with dust that's *not* on your clothes. Your second source seems to address it, saying it's a problem, but then you conclude in the last two sentences that it's not a problem. Why?

Comment: dust has no value, excepted dust of holy books, because you are interested to take it in gniza.

Comment: If you want not to launch mucus, you leave it at its place. If sudainly a mucus is expectored e. g. bronchial mucus, you need to cough it up in situ before walking

Comment: Where is the proof that something of no value may be carried (not on the clothes)?